# Convert DateTime to Epoch timestamp in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a datetime (16 May 2023 10:15:49) in Azure Data Explorer tables and I need to convert this to epoch timestamp (1684232149). I have checked some inbuild functions, but all of them will convert epoch to datetime timestamp.

How to convert datetime to epoch in ADX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow the example named "From Unix time" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datetime-timespan-arithmetic).

```
let toUnixTime = (dt: datetime) { 
    (dt - datetime(1970-01-01)) / 1s 
};
print result = toUnixTime(datetime(2023-05-16 10:15:49))
```